# How to delete all old images from Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to delete all the images from 2012 to July 2015 from my Wordpress site because of the image copyright issue. And I also want to keep all the articles or pages without broken images links after deleted the images.If I manually delete one image (all thumbnails version) then it shows broken image link on the front-end for the article.

any idea?

Comment: i suppose you know how to delete the media from ftp. Now for the broken image link, you should do some codes. In the file php who is charged to display the type of post (ex:default,image,video), you can test the existance of file, And if it doesn't exist, you can either make a photo by default or delete the div of image.

Answer (score 0):

Go into an FTP, look for the uploads folder in the theme and the files are named accordingly.

```
uploads/date...
```

You can see all of the images that have been loaded into WordPress in month order and then it drills down into day files.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a folder structure in uploads you could create a script to delete these folders or files, something like this

```
function recursive_remove_directory($directory, $empty=FALSE)
{
    if(substr($directory,-1) == '/')
    {
        $directory = substr($directory,0,-1);
    }
    if(!file_exists($directory) || !is_dir($directory))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }elseif(is_readable($directory))
    {
        $handle = opendir($directory);
        while (FALSE !== ($item = readdir($handle)))
        {
            if($item != '.' && $item != '..')
            {
                $path = $directory.'/'.$item;
                if(is_dir($path)) 
                {
                    recursive_remove_directory($path);
                }else{
                    unlink($path);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
        if($empty == FALSE)
        {
            if(!rmdir($directory))
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Your use this

```
recursive_remove_directory (WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/uploads/2012');
recursive_remove_directory (WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/uploads/2013');
recursive_remove_directory (WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/uploads/2014');
recursive_remove_directory (WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/uploads/2015/01');
recursive_remove_directory (WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/uploads/2015/02');
.....
recursive_remove_directory (WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/uploads/2015/06');
```

Add function in your functions.php file, then occupy the WP_Query and get all the post from 2012 to July 2015, delete the images of the content with something like this:

```
$content = get_the_content ();
$content = preg_replace ("/ <img [^>] + \> / i", "", $ content);
$content = apply_filters ('the_content', $ content);
$content = str_replace (']>', ']]>', $ content);
```

And occupy wp_update_post to update the content, this will remove all images from the content